# 2-step SQL Query..something seems wrong

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm writing what is a pretty simple 2-step SQL Query.

I have one table called Users and another called ProfileCharacteristics.

```
**Users Table:**

UserId [PK]
UserName

**ProfileCharacteristics Table:**

UserId [FK]
.....(other data)
```

I'm trying to get access to (other data), but I only have the UserName available. So what I'm presently doing is running one SQL Query that matches the UserName to the UserId and stores the UserId value.

Then, I'm pulling all values that match to UserId in ProfileCharacteristics in a separate query. I have a gut feeling that I could combine these two queries into one, but I'm not sure how.

Any pointers?

EDIT: The start of a JOIN?

SELECT * FROM ProfileCharacteristics
INNER JOIN Users
ON ....

Comment: Try to use a `JOIN`.  This might help: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with JOINs, but I'm not sure how the query would look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT pc.*
FROM ProfileCharacteristics pc
    JOIN Users u ON pc.UserId = u.UserId
WHERE U.UserName = 'someuser'
```

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)